Why does it seem like two parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$ are needed to match $e^{-r}$ and $k_2\sin(k_1\,r)$ as well as their derivatives $\frac{d}{d\,r}$?
The Spherical Bessel functions that solve the Spherical Helmholtz equation in the Spherical Coordinate system come in four kinds, the Spherical Bessel Functions of the first kind, the Spherical Bessel Functions of the second kind.  The fundamental (propagating) functions are of the form $j_0(r)=\frac{\sin(r)}{r}$, $n_0(r)=\frac{-\cos(r)}{r}$.  In addition, by applying Euler's identity that through a linear combination (using scale factors that include $\sqrt{-1}$) that there are indeed two additional (evanescent) solutions of the form $\frac{e^{-r}}{r}$ and $\frac{e^{r}}{r}$ which are suitable only for $r\ne 0$.  Applying the Lemma below that "If $\left. a(r)\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. b(r)\right|_{r=r_0}$
and $\left. \frac{\partial a(r)}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{ \partial b(r)}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0}$ then $\left. \frac{a(r)}{r}\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{b(r)}{r}\right|_{r=r_0} $ and $\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{ a(r)}{r} \right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{ b(r)}{r} \right|_{r=r_0}$ for $r_0 \ne 0$" applying boundary conditions of equal value $r=r_0$ at the boundary and also equal value can be solved numerically using two scaling factors $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $\left.(k_2) j_0(k_1 r)\right|_{r=r_0}=\left.\frac{e^{-r}}{r}\right|_{r=r_0}$.  Further, by applying the below Lemma, this task is simplified to applying the same boundary conditions on $\left. (k_2) \sin(k_1 r)\right|_{r=r_0}$ and $\left.e^{-r}\right|_{r=r_0}$, where application of the Lemma proves that the boundary conditions on the simpler functions prove the same boundary function on the more complex equations.  Plus the simpler formula has many references to solving the equivalent Schrodinger particle in a potential box problem.
From a plot [from this reference], it seems that there is one bound state that might be nearly a quarter wavelength from the origin wide:



Trying to solve this problem numerically, I have ended up needing two adjustable paramaters.  I arrive at (surprisingly) $k_2=\frac{\pi}{4}=0.785398163397448$.  And also $k_1=6.85$.  The match looks very good from the plots:


The calculated values follow:

I need help understanding:

Why is $k_2=\frac{\pi}{4}$.  Where is this factor of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ coming from?
Is there something unique about the numerical fit I have adjusted $k_1$ and $k_2$ or does it really model the fundamental mode of this system?
There is a special formula for $k_2$.  Is there a corresponding special formula for $k_1$.  If so, what is it?

Lemma: If $\left. a(r)\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. b(r)\right|_{r=r_0}$
and $\left. \frac{\partial a(r)}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{ \partial b(r)}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0}$ then $\left. \frac{a(r)}{r}\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{b(r)}{r}\right|_{r=r_0} $ and $\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{ a(r)}{r} \right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{ b(r)}{r} \right|_{r=r_0}$ for $r_0 \ne 0$
The first part of the Lemma is derivable by inspection, since both $a(r)$ and $b(r)$ can be divided by $r$ so long as $r \ne 0$, which is one of the conditions of the Lemma.
Now for the second part.  Consider $\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{ a(r)}{r} \right|_{r=r_0}=\frac1{r^2}\left.\left(r \frac{\partial a(r)}{\partial r}-a(r)\right)\right|_{r=r_0} \overset{?} = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{ b(r)}{r} \right|_{r=r_0}=\left. \frac1{r^2}\left(r \frac{\partial b(r)}{\partial r}-b(r)\right)\right|_{r=r_0}$. Multiplying both sides by $r^2$ yields:
$$\left.\left(r \frac{\partial a(r)}{\partial r}-a(r)\right)\right|_{r=r_0} \overset{?} = \left.\left(r \frac{\partial b(r)}{\partial r}-b(r)\right)\right|_{r=r_0}$$
Since $\left.a(r)\right|_{r=r_0}=\left.b(r)\right|_{r=r_0}$ then,
$$\left.\left(r \frac{\partial a(r)}{\partial r}\right)\right|_{r=r_0} \overset{?} = \left.\left(r \frac{\partial b(r)}{\partial r}\right)\right|_{r=r_0}$$
And dividing both sides by $r$ (which is possible since $r\ne 0$), then:
$$\left.\left(\frac{\partial a(r)}{\partial r}\right)\right|_{r=r_0} \overset{?} = \left.\left(\frac{\partial b(r)}{\partial r}\right)\right|_{r=r_0}$$
But the above was a given in the Lemma statement, so the Lemma is definitely true.
Update Concerning the Constants $k_1$ and $k_2$
From the below plot for $k_1\, r$ is nearly $k_1\, r \approx \frac{\pi}{2}$; indeed the numerical solution matching the function and the slopes of $k_2\,\sin(k_1\,r)$ and $e^{-r}$ result in $r=0.25$ and $k_1=4*1.09021136017948*\frac{\pi}{2}$, which makes some sense since one expects a solution when the inside propagating function $k_2 \, \sin(k_1 \, r)$ has a negative slope, for $k_1 \, r> \frac{\pi}{2}$.  Also $e^{-r} = e^{-0.25}=0.778800783071405$ :

Updated using a numerical method to find $k_2$ and $k_1$
The calculation of $k_2$ and $k_1$ was updated using a numerical method that I am hoping to describe in more detail further.  Below are the results of the iterations of this method and the resulting constant calculations.  It seems that both $k_2$ and $k_1$ have local minima and because of this, the two parameters are needed to arrive at an absolute minimum:

Discussion Concerning the Mathematical Steps Towards a Solution
To start, it is possible to attempt to model the left side of the equation below with the one parameter $k_1>0$ as follows:
$$\sin\left(k_1\,r\right)=e^{-r} \, \text{ with the derivative }
k_1\,\cos\left(k_1,r\right)=-e^{-r}$$
A solution is sought in the region $0<k_1 \, r< \frac1{2}\pi$ since $e^{-r}>0$ and $sin\left(k_1\,r\right)>0$ for $0<k_1 \, r< \pi$.  Also the derivative $\frac{d}{d\,r}e^{-r}=-e^{-r}$ is negative, so that only happens in the region $\frac1{2} <k_1 r \, < \pi$
However, this runs into the difficulty that it is possible to match position or slope, but not position and slope.  A graph of various quantities to make it easier to see the difficulty is below with its table. Where the slope is matched around $r=0.3$ by adjusting the $k_1$ parameter, the two curves for $\sin\left(k_1\,r\right)$ and $e^{-r}$ are not equally valued. Note that in the table, the quantity
$1 < \left(k_1 \over \frac{\pi}{2}\right) < 2$ in the region $1<r<2$ so that the value $\sin\left(k_1\,r\right)>0$ and so also its slope
$k_1\cos\left(k_1\,r\right)<0$ as for the equality $e^{-r}$ in the right hand side of the equation $\sin(k_r\,r)=e^{-r}$.

The above discussion in this section "Discussion Concerning the Mathematical Steps Towards a Solution" motivates the necessity of the introduction of a second scaling parameter $k_2$ to make it possible to reach a good match of the value and the slope at a good match-point $r$ as well as the range for $k_1 \, r$ being $\frac{\pi}{2}<k_1 \, r < \pi $.  Thus because of this necessity the new functions being matched are:
$$
k_2\,sin(k_1\,r)=e^{-r} \underset{implies} \implies k_2\,sin(\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2})=e^{-r}
\\ \underset{implies}\implies
k_2\,cos(\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=e^{-r}
=e^{-\left(r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}}
=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\,e^{-\left(r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
$$
$$
k_2\,sin(k_1\,r)=e^{-r} \underset{implies} 
\implies
k_2\,k_1\,cos(k_1\,r)=-e^{-r}
\underset{implies} 
\implies
k_1\,\frac{cos(k_1\,r)}{sin(k_1\,r)}=-1
$$
Using the identities for $cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ then
$$
k_1\,\frac{\displaystyle \cos\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
{\displaystyle \sin\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=-1
$$
The substitution of the identities are then made:
$$
k_1\,\frac{\displaystyle \sin\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
{\displaystyle \cos\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=1
$$
And hence there are the functions with the two scaling parameters necessary to make a good match.

Sorry, but is there an explicit main equation you want to solve for $k_1$ or maybe $k_2$?
